# Double delegate call doesn't work

Tags: contract-development, delegatecall

To create an upgradeable contract I have to use multiple proxies. The contract applies to Proxy A, then Proxy A applies to Proxy B. But delegatecall doesn't work in this case.

The simplified code of my contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


contract A {
    uint256 public value = 100;

    function mul() public {
        value *= 2;
    }
}

contract B {
    uint256 public value = 200;
    address a;

    constructor(address _a) {
        a = _a;
    }

    function delegate() public {
        a.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("mul()")));
    }
}

contract C {
    uint256 public value = 500;
    address b;

    constructor(address _b) {
        b = _b;
    }

    function delegate() public {
        b.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("delegate()")));
    }
}
```

`delegate()` function works only if it called at contract B

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When, in `C`, you do `b.delegatecall(`, what happens is that:

- the code used is that of `B`
- the storage used is that of `C`

And `B` and `C` have the same storage layout:

- both the `uint value` are located on storage slot `0`.
- with `address a` and `address b` located on storage slot `1`

So now you are executing `B`'s code with `C`'s storage. And you ask `a.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("mul()")));`. What the underlying bytecode does is actually take `C`'s value at storage slot `1`, in effect `b`, and use that as `a`. So you are about to `delegatecall` on `B` again.

And you call `mul()` on `B`? There is no such function, so it does nothing. In fact, depending on your version of Solidity, this call would silently fail or not.

It's working as expected :)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very comprehensive. I wonder if it is possible to achieve what Mikky want to do.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `delegatecall` the code of the called contract is used with the calling contract state.

So in the first `delegatecall` you are calling `B` contract code with `C` contract state.
In the second `delegatecall` you are calling `A` contract code with `C` contract state.

So you cannot do a simple nested proxy in a naive way.

If you want to solve this, you should first check if the inner proxy is in fact a proxy, meaning that it has an delegate address set (in your example address `a`)
And if so set the `C` delegate address to be `B` delegate address, delegate the call to b (the original `C` delegate address) and then revert the change of the delegate address of contract `C`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


contract A {
    uint256 public value = 100;

    function mul() public {
        value *= 2;
    }
}

contract B {
    uint256 public value = 200;
    address a;

    constructor(address _a) {
        a = _a;
    }

    function delegate() public {
        a.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("mul()")));
    }
}

contract C {
    uint256 public value = 500;
    address b;

    constructor(address _b) {
        b = _b;
    }

    function delegate() public {
        address orgB = b;
        if (b.a != address(0)) {
            b = b.a;
        }
        orgB.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("delegate()")));
        b = orgB;
    }
}
```

For more on that, you can see how to update a proxy to a nested proxy:
[06a396bd](https://github.com/poanetwork/poa-bridge-contracts/pull/140/commits/06a396bd7e52b590437b66bed3c23f3bcaf97781)